# What is the corner house number?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

The Singh family lives in a housing development full of Scientists and engineers (god forbid!). The Home Owners have come up with weird ways of numbering their houses.

> K Street is all engineers and M street is all mathematicians.
>
> Turns out Mr. Singh is an engineer and of course Mrs. (Dr.) Singh is a
>   Mathematician! So they have a house at the corner of K and M street.

So assuming they followed the patterns for both streets, what is their house number?

Hint

> Engineers like "Metrics" Think Metric Measurements and !

[image]

Comment: You have to think laterally with respect to which street?

Comment: That would be a clear hint @Arnaud Mortier

Comment: But a very good question none-the-less

Comment: rot13(gur yrggre rz vf bar gubhfnaq va Ebzna ahzrenyf, naq gur yrggre xnl va ybjre pnfr vf gur zhygvcyvre sbe bar gubhfnaq va gur zrgevp flfgrz), but I don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: Judging by the correct answer, #1 K street should actually have no number at all...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the house number is

> 1000

Since K street is all engineers,

> In Roman Numerals, 1000, 100, 500, and 1 translate to M, C, D, and I. When combining these with a metric measurement (metres) per @DEEM, we see that we get MM (millimetres), CM (centimetres), DM (decimetres), and M (metres) which are increasing units of length. Thanks to @Levieux for the assist!

Since M street is all mathematicians,

> In Roman Numerals, M translates to 1000, which could mean that all house numbers (ie. 1000, 2000, 6000) are all multiples of 1000. @Braegh has further noted that the house numbers follow the pattern x! times 1000, as 1! = 1, 2! = 2, and 3! = 6. Thanks, @Braegh!

The house number

> 1000 meets both criteria.

Comment: Membrane Capacity___  It is lot simpler @El-Guest

Comment: How does the updated answer look, @DEEM ?

Comment: Also, rot13(Jvgu 1000, gurer pbhyq nyfb or n frdhrapr va gur Z fgerrg ubhfrf, bs gur sbez ((cerivbhf ubhfr ahzore/1000)^2)*1000 + (cerivbhf ubhfr ahzore))

Comment: Hint: K is significant. Then lateral thinking.

Comment: @Imus if you check my edits, that’s what I had initially but I was told it’s simpler than that.

Comment: hmm, I missed DEEM responded to that in that it was simpler. Current one feels worse to me anyway hence my comment. Maybe we're still missing something then

Comment: I think the M street pattern is rot13(1000 gvzrf k!, jurer k vf gur ahzore bs gur ubhfr, fgnegvat sebz gur pbeare. Gur arkg bar jbhyq or gjragl-sbhe gubhfnaq, va guvf cnggrea.)

Comment: Good spot, @Braegh!!

Comment: Perhaps the letters on K street stand for rot13(zvyyv, pragv, qrpv; bayl gur V qbrfa'g ernyyl svg va gurer)?

Comment: Ubj nobhg ZZ PZ QZ Z?

Comment: How does this look now, @DEEM?

Comment: The Roman numeral part holds for mm, cm, and dm, but you gloss over the fact that im isn't a unit.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer.**

I believe the answer is

> 50

Because

> the engineer sequence turned in roman numerals would then be **L**CDI, which is engineer slang for Leakage Current Detection And Interruption.

Also

> A mathematician will tell you that there are billions of good reasons 50, 2000 and 6000 could be consecutive terms of a sequence, although OEIS has no results (perhaps that's what makes it special: it's the only sequence of three $\leq 4$-digits numbers that OEIS doesn't know an extension of :) )

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> 900

Because on M street:

> If you convert to roman numerals, each house has two characters with one being an M $\rightarrow$ MM = 2000, $\overline VM$ = 6000. So the Singh's house could be CM = 900, MI = 1001, MV = 1005, MC = 1100, MD = 1500, etc.

Because on K street:

> The letter K represents a thousand. It doesn't make sense to represent a number under 1 or over 999 with a K. Therefore the number is limited between 1 -> 999. This leaves CM = 900 as the only remaining house number.

Comment: How is VM=6000?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I think like this: $\overline VM$?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial

I don't actually have an answer, yet. Here's something, though:

> K could be *kilo* and M could be *mega* as both have something to do with numbers and it looks like the numbers on K (kilo) Street are smaller than the numbers on M (mega) Street by a factor of 10, so... **maybe 1,000** to mark the transition point?

Might be worth noting that

> K and M can be kilometers, as well, which is another metric measurement...

Comment: On the right path. Think another metric measurement. Your answer (number) is correct though, just like @El-Guests

Comment: @DEEM - Am I _still_ on the right path? Have I advanced? Did I go backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Converting my Aug 7 comment into an answer:

The house number is

> 1000

because on M street:

> the letter M is one thousand in Roman numerals

and on K street:

> the letter K in lower case is the multiplier for one thousand in the metric system

Comment: Then how do you explain the other house numbers @shoover? What pattern?